# Updating values with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Am I updating 'fruits' properly? I would think fruits.push('something') would trigger the useEffect hook? or using setFruits would cause a re-render?

```
const Fruits = () => {
const [fruitInput, setFruitInput] = useState("")
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState(['Apple', 'Orange'])

const addFruit = fruit => {
   console.log('addFruit', fruit)
   fruits.push(fruit)
   setFruits(fruits)
}

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('fruits was updated', fruits)
 }, [fruits])

 return (
 <>
    <ul>{fruits.map((fruit, index) => <li key={index}>{fruit}</li>)}</ul>
    <input type="text" onChange={ e => setFruitInput(e.target.value) } value={fruitInput} />
    <button onClick={() => addFruit(fruitInput)}>Add Fruit</button>
 </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mutating the `fruits` array in place, so React doesn't see its changes and does not trigger a render. Add the item to newly created array instead:

```
const addFruit = fruit => {
   console.log('addFruit', fruit)
   setFruits([...fruits, fruit])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use setFruits properly. Refactor

```
   console.log('addFruit', fruit)
   fruits.push(fruit)
   setFruits(fruits)
}
```

to

```
const addFruit = fruit => {
   console.log('addFruit', fruit)
   setFruits(fruits=>([...fruits, fruit]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below implementation should resolve your issue:-

```js
const Fruits = () => {
  const [fruitInput, setFruitInput] = useState("");
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState(["Apple", "Orange"]);

  const addFruit = () => {
    const newFruits = [...fruits];
    newFruits.push(fruitInput);
    setFruits(newFruits);
    console.log(newFruits);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fruits was updated", fruits);
  }, [fruits]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {fruits.map((fruit, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{fruit}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setFruitInput(e.target.value)}
        value={fruitInput}
      />
      <button onClick={addFruit}>Add Fruit</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Explanation:**

When you use `[fruits]` in `useEffect` then it does deep comparison, so you have to ensure that the new value in `fruits` is different than what was there earlier. Simply pushing value in array won't trigger the update.

Comment: I'm sure you meant shallow comparison, i.e. that only the reference to the variable `fruits` references a new array object. Pushing values into an array doesn't return a new array reference.

Comment: Yup that's correct. I wanted to use the simple language just to ensure that other person understands.